# xcode change code signing identity by ruby gem xcodeproj

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, xcode-project

I'm totally new to Ruby but managed to change the project based code signing identity and provisioning profile in xcode like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'xcodeproj'

xcproj = Xcodeproj::Project.open("MyProject.xcodeproj")

xcproj.build_configurations.each do |item|
    item.build_settings['CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]'] = "iOS Development: xxxxxx xxxx (xxxxxxxxx)"
end

xcproj.build_configurations.each do |item|
    item.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]'] = "628352b1-9b78-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
end

xcproj.save
```

My problem is the target based code signing identity and provisioning profile will override the project based one. But I can't find a method to directly set the target based one. Hope someone can help here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `xcodebuild` tool to change the code sign identity and provisioning profile, instead of directly editing the project (.xcodeproj) file:

`xcodebuild -sdk <iphoneos> -target <target_name> -configuration <Debug> CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iOS Development: xxxxxx xxxx (xxxxxxxxx)" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="628352b1-9b78-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the targets of the project by calling `native_targets` on `project`, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'xcodeproj'

xcproj = Xcodeproj::Project.open("MyProject.xcodeproj")
target = xcproj.native_targets.detect { |target| target.name == "MyTarget" }

target.build_configurations.each do |item|
  item.build_settings['CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]'] = "iOS Development: xxxxxx xxxx (xxxxxxxxx)"
end

target.build_configurations.each do |item|
  item.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]'] = "628352b1-9b78-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
end

xcproj.save
```